# Leaflet.markercluster keyboard resize mobile

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using the super useful Leaflet.markercluster for leaflet which has been great for performance because of the nice getExpandedVisibleBounds feature.

One problem I am running into is on mobile devices with the keyboard changing the viewport/bounds. When I enter an input box and the keyboard pops up, it shrinks the map viewport. After the keyboard goes away the viewport/bounds don't seem to update for the markercluster. The map is fully visible again but markers that are on the lower half of the map (where the keyboard was) are now not visible. Panning the map and zooming in and out don't seem to fix it. After a minute or so of use it seems to correct itself and the markers and now visible on the whole viewport again.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a live example that exhibits this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not a live one. The problem is actually only on Android. On iOS, the keyboard covers up half the page without resizing the window. On Android, they keyboard shrinks the window to make room for it. From my understanding there is no way to prevent that from happening on Android.

Comment: So I have the map with markers. There is a marker search input. When I type in the input, the keyboard comes up and squishes everything. I select a marker to open from the results returned from the search. When I do this the viewport is all messed up so it doesn't show the markers where the keyboard was.